# Should I use a separate optimizer for each generator network of a CycleGAN in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm currently debugging a GAN based image-to-image translation model that is based on CycleGAN, or more specifically the [DeepPhotoEnhancer](https://github.com/nothinglo/Deep-Photo-Enhancer). Looking at examples for writing the training loop, some, such as in the official Tensorflow tutorial, use a separate optimizer for the A-to-B and B-to-A generators, whereas others I've found on various GitHub repos use a single optimizer for both A-to-B and B-to-A generators.

My questions is: does it matter whether I use separate optimizers or a singular optimizer for both generator networks? Why / why not?

Example of an optimizer for each generator network (from the [official Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan#training)):

```
@tf.function
def train_step(real_x, real_y):
  # persistent is set to True because the tape is used more than
  # once to calculate the gradients.
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    # Generator G translates X -> Y
    # Generator F translates Y -> X.

    fake_y = generator_g(real_x, training=True)
    cycled_x = generator_f(fake_y, training=True)

    fake_x = generator_f(real_y, training=True)
    cycled_y = generator_g(fake_x, training=True)

    # same_x and same_y are used for identity loss.
    same_x = generator_f(real_x, training=True)
    same_y = generator_g(real_y, training=True)

    disc_real_x = discriminator_x(real_x, training=True)
    disc_real_y = discriminator_y(real_y, training=True)

    disc_fake_x = discriminator_x(fake_x, training=True)
    disc_fake_y = discriminator_y(fake_y, training=True)

    # calculate the loss
    gen_g_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_y)
    gen_f_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_x)

    total_cycle_loss = calc_cycle_loss(real_x, cycled_x) + calc_cycle_loss(real_y, cycled_y)

    # Total generator loss = adversarial loss + cycle loss
    total_gen_g_loss = gen_g_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_y, same_y)
    total_gen_f_loss = gen_f_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_x, same_x)

    disc_x_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_x, disc_fake_x)
    disc_y_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_y, disc_fake_y)

  # Calculate the gradients for generator and discriminator
  generator_g_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_g_loss, generator_g.trainable_variables)
  generator_f_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_f_loss, generator_f.trainable_variables)

  discriminator_x_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_x_loss, discriminator_x.trainable_variables)
  discriminator_y_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_y_loss, discriminator_y.trainable_variables)

  # Apply the gradients to the optimizer
  generator_g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_gradients, generator_g.trainable_variables))
  generator_f_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_f_gradients, generator_f.trainable_variables))

  discriminator_x_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_x_gradients, discriminator_x.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_y_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_y_gradients, discriminator_y.trainable_variables))
```

Example of a single optimizer for both generator networks (from [LynnHo on GitHub](https://github.com/LynnHo/CycleGAN-Tensorflow-2/blob/master/train.py)):

```
@tf.function
def train_G(A, B):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        A2B = G_A2B(A, training=True)
        B2A = G_B2A(B, training=True)
        A2B2A = G_B2A(A2B, training=True)
        B2A2B = G_A2B(B2A, training=True)
        A2A = G_B2A(A, training=True)
        B2B = G_A2B(B, training=True)

        A2B_d_logits = D_B(A2B, training=True)
        B2A_d_logits = D_A(B2A, training=True)

        A2B_g_loss = g_loss_fn(A2B_d_logits)
        B2A_g_loss = g_loss_fn(B2A_d_logits)
        A2B2A_cycle_loss = cycle_loss_fn(A, A2B2A)
        B2A2B_cycle_loss = cycle_loss_fn(B, B2A2B)
        A2A_id_loss = identity_loss_fn(A, A2A)
        B2B_id_loss = identity_loss_fn(B, B2B)

        G_loss = (A2B_g_loss + B2A_g_loss) + (A2B2A_cycle_loss + B2A2B_cycle_loss) * args.cycle_loss_weight + (A2A_id_loss + B2B_id_loss) * args.identity_loss_weight

    G_grad = t.gradient(G_loss, G_A2B.trainable_variables + G_B2A.trainable_variables)
    G_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(G_grad, G_A2B.trainable_variables + G_B2A.trainable_variables))

    return A2B, B2A, {'A2B_g_loss': A2B_g_loss,
                      'B2A_g_loss': B2A_g_loss,
                      'A2B2A_cycle_loss': A2B2A_cycle_loss,
                      'B2A2B_cycle_loss': B2A2B_cycle_loss,
                      'A2A_id_loss': A2A_id_loss,
                      'B2B_id_loss': B2B_id_loss}
```

Comment: YES, you need an optimizer for each independent architecture.

Comment: Why is this the case? Does that mean the second provided example will not train correctly?

Comment: I had similar doubts  recently, but I was concerned with PyTorch code . In "official" code parameters are joined and it makes sense (because of cycle part of loss - `G_A(G_B(B))`). I think it can be done also with separate optimizer (in PyTorch), but I'm not sure are the both  TensorFlow implementations  you show are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Tensorflow user but maybe they should be similar to PyTorch. According to official PyTorch CycleGAN repo there are no difference between using single optimizer or using two different optimizer but just simplifies the code if you use single optimizer.

The reason why there's no difference is because even if you use single optimizer the parameters are independently updated. What optimizer does is just updating its tracking, corresponding weights. This idea will help you understand why there's no difference.

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues?q=is%3Aissue+optimizer+is%3Aclosed

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/177

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/issues/1381

Good luck.